# ruby on rails, session expire notification

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, session

Im Working with ruby 1.9.3 and rails 3.2.

My actual session handling looks like:

**Session helper**

```
    def sign_in(user)
            cookies[:remember_token] = {value: user.remember_token, expires: 20.minutes.from_now.utc}
            self.current_user = user
    end

    def sign_out
            self.current_user = nil
            cookies.delete(:remember_token)
    end

    def signed_in?
            if current_user.nil?
                    return false
            else
                    cookies[:remember_token] = {value: current_user.remember_token, expires: 20.minutes.from_now.utc}
            end

    def current_user=(user)
            @current_user = user
    end

    def current_user
            @current_user ||= User.find_by_remember_token(cookies[:remember_token])

    end
```

**Application Controller**

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :check_signin
  protect_from_forgery
  include SessionsHelper

  def check_signin
        unless signed_in?
        redirect_to signin_path
        end
  end
end
```

if the session is expired, i want to inform the user @ the sign in page. how can i check if the session is expired? Please give a code example.

Comment: How you implement the `self.current_user=` and `current_user` methods? Are you using session or not ?

Comment: i've added the methods above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your cookie expires in 20 minutes, you can't differentiate a new user from a user with an expired session. A quick and dirty solution, would be to test the existence of a google analytics cookie to know if the user has an expired session.

```
def check_signin
  unless signed_in?
    flash[:notice] = "Your session has expired" if cookie['_utma']
    redirect_to signin_path
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

@sailor solution is right, but you shouldn't use "_utma" cookie.
I'd rather create a new one instead!

Comment: shouldn't this be a comment under @sailor's answer? Or at least an edit to his answer?