# auto-session-timeout - Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, session

I'm new to Ruby on Rails. Im trying to implement a session time out using gem
auto-session-time out.Thing is my session is getting expired correctly. But what i want is that while the session get expired i want the url to go to a specific link(say www.abcd.com). Also i want a method to be called while session gets expired. Right now after 1 minute when i reload my session gets expired, but it relocates to the same page.

I have this in my application controller

```
auto_session_timeout 1.minute
```

and in my routes

```
match 'active'  => 'sessions#active'
match 'timeout' => 'sessions#timeout'
```

and in my sessionscontroller

```
def active
   p "--------------Active--------------"
  end

  def timeout

        p "------------TimeOut--------------"
        RestClient.post 'https://www.abcd.com', :ApplicationName => 'ABCD Website&Application', :URL => 'http://www.xyz.com/login/'
      end
```

i thought i would get this method while session gets expired. But its not working. Thanks in advance

Comment: If I understand you right, why can't you add a `before_filter authenticate` or something that checks if the session is expired and redirect the user from there ?? Shouldn't that help ?

Comment: @PamioSolanky Hi as i said earlier, i realy dont know how to do that. 1 friend told me it would be easy to do this with this gem, thats why i went this way. Can u pls help me with the way you said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit your file- config/initializers/session_store.rb

```
App::Application.config.session_store :cookie_store, 
                                         :key => "_yourapp_session",
                                         :expire_after => 2.minutes
```

And then in you application controller:
`before_filter: authenticate`

```
 def authenticate
    redirect_to some_path if session[:session_key].nil?
 end
```

Note: You will manually have to set the session key.
Also, check this answer which should help [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13934267/ruby-on-rails-session-expire-notification)